# 1 Click Screenshot and Save

Tags: firefox, screenshot

In my job, I need to take and preserve various screenshots every day. All of these shots are in Firefox only.

Now, I know the traditional way of taking screenshots, but it's too inconvenient, if one has to take multiple screenshots every day.

So, I am looking for a convenient way (1 Click) to capture and save screen in a designated folder.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Screengrab!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab-fix-version/) firefox addon.

It can capture the screen and save it as a file for you either when using a hotkey or by clicking the icon. There are a lot of configuration options so you should be able to configure it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try some free snipping tool combined with various features to capture screenshots in PC?

I am afraid to be banned if recommend any third-party software.
Well, I am using a snipping tool named Snipaste to capture screenshot during my work.

[image: screenshot of Snipaste]

Comment: Such vague "answer" should be a comment, if anything.

Comment: The answer has been updated.